# Session Variable in ASP.NET returns previous value in ModalBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, session-variables, modalpopupextender

I have a question regarding passing Session Variables to a text-box in an Update Panel (which is displayed in a Modal PopUp). 
This is the code I have so far:

**ASPX CODE:**

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Link" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="panel_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="ClientButton" PopupControlID="UpdatePanel1" OkControlID="OKButton">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Button ID="ClientButton" runat="server" Text="Launch Modal Popup (Client)" style="display:none;" />
```

**CODE BEHIND (C#):**

```cs
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label lbl_nme = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lbl_name");
    String string_nme = lbl_nme.Text.ToString();
    Session["Name"] = string_nme;
    mpe.Show();
}

protected void panel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = (string)(Session["Name"]);
}
```

So basically I have a GridView with name, address etc… When the user clicks on a link in a row, then the value for the name field of that row is saved as a session variable. Then a Modal PopUp is displayed. The Modal PopUp should then show the Name which was saved as a Session variable.

The code sort of works. What I’m experiencing is that when I click a row, the Label1.Text in the Modal PopUp is empty. So if I close the PopUp then click another link in another row, the PopUp then displays the Name of the row that was clicked previously.

In other words.. If row 1 has Name “Kevin” and row 2 has Name “Nathaniel”, and I click a link to open the Modal PopUp of row 1, I would expect the PopUp to display “Kevin”. But it doesn’t. The first time I click a link after rebuilding the application, nothing is displayed. But say I click row 2 after clicking row1, then the Modal PopUp displays the value of the row I clicked before, i.e. “Kevin” when I expect it to be “Nathaniel”.

I hope I didn’t confuse anyone. I’m a newbie and I’m just getting into this stuff, so I’d appreciate it if someone could help me out, preferably with examples of code etc.

Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Load" event (`panel_Load`) occurs *before* the "Click" event (`LinkButton1_Click`) so it only sees the *previous* value.

The quick fix is to set the label in the "Click" event as well. Unless ViewState is enabled for the label (ick!) the label *may* have to be [re]set in the "Load" as well, depending upon when/how updates occur.

See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) and  [ASP.NET Application and Page Life Cycle: Page Events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle#Zooming%20ASP.NET%20page%20events).

Happy coding.